# Change connection string in MS Excel 2013 powerpivot

Tags: c#, excel, powerpivot

I am working on same solution where i need to update connection strings of multiple files in Bulk.But , Its working for MS Excel 2010 and not for Excel 2013.

> Exception Result : "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Code Snippet :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ppWorkbook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileNameBox.Text);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Connections connections = ppWorkbook.Connections;

string newConnectionString = "Connection String";

try
{
     foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookConnection connection in connections)
     {
          connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection = newConnectionString;
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

It occurs while assigning the connection string to OLEDBConnection.
Need solution for MS Excel 2013 c#.

Answer (score 0):

Every connection has the property "InModel". When this property is set it's a powerpivot connection and can't be updated with excel api. When you try this, you'll get the posted error message.
You have to use the dlls from the powerpivot addin.

Answer (score 0):

You could do assignment if adding `OLEDB;` at the beginning of your connection string. Had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302778/why-setting-oledbconnection-connection-throws-exception-hresult-0x800a03ec/38920632#38920632).